# Fixing cells in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way or method of fixing a range in Excel. For example you can have an absolute range such as $A$1:$C$500 but if a row is deleted within that range the range will change to $A$1:$C$499.

This can be especially frustrating when you send out a protected sheet with a formula in a column and then someone deletes something and the formula shows #REF, which just needs the formula to be copied down again, which can not be done by the user as the sheet is protected.

Comment: Can you use Indirect in your Formula? if what is the Formula and where is it written, can you use Row()-1?

Comment: Can you protect the sheet where the user deletes the row? Indirect can work, but is volatile, so should be avoided if there is a lot of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel allows you to assign names to ranges in the worksheet. This provides more easier way of working with formulas.

- Select "define name" under formula tab
- Provide a name that you want to call your range and give the range formula in the refers to formula box, `=INDIRECT("A1"):INDIRECT("C500")` and press OK
- You could now use this name in all your formulas.

for example,

`name = Rangename
formula to use = SUM(Rangename)`

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: This has the same problem, when you delete a row or column, the range defined in the named range changes.

Comment: You should be using indirect then. That might help

Comment: @Naz I have updated the answer. Please check this and let me know if its working